# How to count the occurrence of specific items on grouped items of a csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, count

I have a .csv file with the following columns

```
Concelho    Classe 
Lisbon  A+
Porto   C
Faro    B-
Porto   A+
Porto   B-
Lisbon  B-
Lisbon  C
Lisbon  A+
Lisbon  A+
Lisbon  A+
Lisbon  B-
Lisbon  D
Lisbon  B-
Porto   E
Porto   E
Faro    C
Faro    B-
Faro    C
```

And I would like to obtain a dataframe where I have grouped "concelho" and the number of occurrences of classes (B-, A, A+):
such as...

```
Concelho    count Class (B-,A, A+)
Lisbon  7
Porto   2
Faro    2
```

I tried to use groupby.count() or groupby.value_counts() from panda but I didn't manage to define the counting conditions (Classe = B- or A, or A+)

Comment: When you want to groupby a subset, always filter that subset first and then do a groupby on that subset. Anurag just posted the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use boolean masking,`groupby()`, `isin()` and `rename()` method:

```
resultdf=df[df['Classe'].isin(['B-','A','A+'])].groupby('Concelho',as_index=False).agg({'Classe':'count'}).rename(columns={'Classe':'count'})
```

Now if you `resultdf` you will get your desired output:

```
    Concelho    count
0   Faro          2
1   Lisbon        7
2   Porto         2
```

**Or**

you can skip the use of `rename()` method by using `agg()` method with named `tuples`

So you can also do this by using boolean masking,`groupby()`, `isin()` method:

```
resultdf=df[df['Classe'].isin(['B-','A','A+'])]\
                         .groupby('Concelho',as_index=False)\
                         .agg(count=('Classe','count'))
```

Comment: @Umar.H thanks for your suggestion...Added this in the answer **:)**